# Is there any tool available for Windows XP to fix IE9 issues?

Tags: javascript, html, css, conditional-statements

I have a style issue in IE9. Menu bars not aligned correctly. I am using Windows XP only.But IE9 will be available for >Vista only. How can I test and fix IE9 issues in Windows XP OS ?

Here I am attaching the screen shot of the issue I am facing.

**Error in IE 9:**

[image]

**Correct Layout in Chrome:**

[image]

Comment: Is the issue happening in IE 8 also?

Comment: You can add link to your page so we can check this bug.

Comment: @karthick : I want to fix for IE9 only bro.

Comment: @ant_Ti: did u note the url bro ? What are the issues in menu bar. How can I write Conditional comment for it ?

Comment: @balajimca: Yeah i can understand that but if you are fixing in IE8 then i think that should somewhat resolve the issue in ie 9 and your main problem is that you need to fix that from windows XP. What is the document type you are using?

Comment: Install Windows 7/8. Windows XP is outdated, even Microsoft has stopped supporting it and that says alot about the quality the system is having right now. My be your system, may be your Browsers renders different on XP. Think about it.

Comment: @karthick : <!DOCTYPE html> bro

Comment: @balajimca How can we suppose to know the issue without seeing the code? this is not a issue of Windows XP or other OS. It is issue of a browser. right? post the code please.

Comment: @karthick : its working fine in IE8.

Comment: Press f12 whilst in the browser and use its built in tools

Comment: Check and make sure you're runging Browser Mode: IE9 /  Document Mode: IE9 standards.

Comment: @Mr_Green : Yes bro. It can be fixed use of IE9 only. I've no environment to install IE9. I want to know is there any tool available to fix IE issues in Windows XP.

Comment: @balajimca IE9 has its own developer tool which works if you press F12 when focus is on browser. Anyway, [**check this link**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below links:

- [**Virtual PC VHD's**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575) ([*readme*](http://blog.reybango.com/2013/02/04/making-internet-explorer-testing-easier-with-new-ie-vms/))
- [**spoon.net**](http://spoon.net/apps/ie-9.0) (*online tool which let you have experience of IE 9 browser*).
- [**IE tester**](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).
- [**Developer tool for IE9**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18359) provided by MSDN. (*Supports Windows XP*).

**HINT**: *For more links, search in google for `online virtual browsers`*

Instead of doing this, I recommend you to install latest version of OS to support all browsers.

---

Honestly, [I don't recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10445781/1577396) `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` .

Comment: Thanks for your links bro. I am trying spoon.net as you suggested.

Comment: @balajimca I updated my post with more links. Might be helpful to you.

Answer (score -2):

Please post some code snippet so that we can point you in the right direction.

Since you said that your code is working in IE8

You can use this as a hot fix for now.

```
<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=8”/>
```

This will make ie9 fallback into ie8 mode.  If you still not fixed and you need ie 9 in windows xp use some virtual machine.