# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> What does this code do?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, datepicker, meta

i wonder what does this  do? Since i did put date picker on my site, and the coding provide with this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` code. The date picker provide 2 ways to choose date which is from the calendar itself and from drop down menu. So far I have no problem to pick date using calendar. The problem if i removed this code (`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`), my date won't changed according to the value selected. But once i add back the coding, i can get my date using drop down list but it's only work on IE, not in Chrome. I just wonder if there's any way for me to make sure the calendar work fine in IE and Chrome using date picker from drop-down list and calendar.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445781/using-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-8-mode-in-sites-good-pr  ......(as in, a google search would tell you the answer). Regardless, what controls are you using for your date time pickers?

Comment: what i understand that when i put this tag, it will read my code just like i'm using IE7, but since i'm using IE9, so when i remove that tag, maybe some coding for the date picker not supported by IE9.
http://www.iiadesign.com/calendar/calendar_datepicker.php.htm i'm using the date picker with 3 drop down menus..

Comment: I would therefore pick another date time picker. Many exist, many exist in jQuery. If they work, you know your existing ones have issues with IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)

Answer (score 0):

X-UA-Compatible specifies the version of IE which your page has been designed for. There is a topic on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge) describing this meta attribute, it may helps you

Comment: so if the code is not running in once i removed it/not running in chrome, i need to change the coding?or is that any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using it this way - 
< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">

Comment: Care to go into a little more detail? The question seems to be "what's going on" as much as "how do I fix it".